Dialogflow training phrases - Google Cloud Essentials
export const training_file_upload = async (req, res) => {
  const projectId = req.body.project_id;
  //    const agentId = req.body.agent_id
  const training_file = req.files[0];

  if (!req.files || !training_file) {
    return res.status(400).json({ error: "No file uploaded" });
  }
  //    console.log(projectId);
  //    console.log(training_file);
  try {
    const uploadResponse = await trainingFileUpload(projectId, training_file);
    // console.log(uploadResponse);
    if (
      uploadResponse &&
      uploadResponse.msg.data &&
      uploadResponse.msg.data.name
    ) {
      res.status(200).json({ msg: "file uploaded successfully" });
    } else {
      res.status(400).json({ msg: "file uploading failed" });
    }
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(400).json({ error: err.message });
  }
};

export const trainingFileUpload = async (project_id, trainingFile) => {
  const dialogflow = await google.dialogflow({
    version: "v2",
    auth: await authenticate(),
  });
  try {
    const agent_id = (
      await dialogflow.projects.getAgent({ parent: `projects/${project_id}` })
    ).data.displayName;
    console.log(agent_id);
    const fileContent = fs.readFileSync(trainingFile.path, "utf-8");
    // console.log(file);
    const trainingPhrases = fileContent.split("\n").map((line) => ({
      parts: [{ text: line.trim() }],
    }));
    console.log(trainingPhrases);
    const fileUploadResp = await dialogflow.projects.agent.import({
      parent: `projects/${project_id}`,
      agentUri: `projects/${project_id}/agent/${agent_id}`,
      agentContent: {
        trainingPhrases: trainingPhrases,
      },
    });
    // console.log(fileUploadResp.data);
    return { msg: fileUploadResp };
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err.message);
  }
};


I am trying to implement a google dialogFlow Uploading functionality to train my dialogFlow agent in google cloud essentials.
....

This is the code for uploading a training file content to our
dialogflow conversation section of training. I am getting a
successful response whenever I test the code but I am not getting the
file contents visible to my dialog flow conversation UI.

Any tweak in the code that will make it function will be very much appreciated.
Thanks,
Aniket
